# pthread win32 version? (Mongoose)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, pthreads, mongoose-web-server, pthreads-win32

Please tell me what difference between pthread versions: VC2, VCE2 and VSE2? How to choose which of them I must use with Visual C++ Express 2010 for Mongoose webserver library?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- VCE - MSVC dll with C++ exception handling
- VSE - MSVC dll with structured exception handling
- VC  - MSVC dll with C cleanup code

Which one you'd want to use with VC++ Express 2010 depends on how you want pthread clean up to be handled.  If you're linking this to the Mongoose webserver (which I'm not familiar with), I think you'll want to use the exception handling model as that code is compiled with.

The pthreads Win32 library goes into a fair bit of detail:

> ### Library naming
>
> Because the library is being built
>   using various exception handling
>   schemes and compilers - and because
>   the library may not work reliably if
>   these are mixed in an application,
>   each different version of the library
>   has it's own name.
>
> Note 1: the incompatibility is really
>   between EH implementations of the
>   different compilers. It should be
>   possible to use the standard C version
>   from either compiler with C++
>   applications built with a different
>   compiler. If you use an EH version of
>   the library, then you must use the
>   same compiler for the application.
>   This is another complication and
>   dependency that can be avoided by
>   using only the standard C library
>   version.
>
> Note 2: if you use a standard C
>   pthread*.dll with a C++ application,
>   then any functions that you define
>   that are intended to be called via
>   pthread_cleanup_push() must be
>   __cdecl.
>
> Note 3: the intention was to also name
>   either the VC or GC version (it should
>   be arbitrary) as pthread.dll,
>   including pthread.lib and libpthread.a
>   as appropriate. This is no longer
>   likely to happen.
>
> Note 4: the compatibility number was
>   added so that applications can
>   differentiate between binary
>   incompatible versions of the libs and
>   dlls.
>
> In general:   pthread[VG]{SE,CE,C}c.dll
>     pthread[VG]{SE,CE,C}c.lib
>
> where:    [VG] indicates the compiler
>     V   - MS VC, or     G   - GNU C
>
> {SE,CE,C} indicates the exception
>   handling scheme   SE  - Structured EH,
>   or    CE  - C++ EH, or    C   - no exceptions
>   - uses setjmp/longjmp
>
> c   - DLL compatibility number
>   indicating ABI and API
>           compatibility with applications built against
>           any snapshot with the same compatibility number.
>           See 'Version numbering' below.
>
> The name may also be suffixed by a 'd'
>   to indicate a debugging version of the
>   library. E.g. pthreadVC2d.lib.
>   Debugging versions contain additional
>   information for debugging (symbols
>   etc) and are often not optimised in
>   any way (compiled with optimisation
>   turned off).
>
> For example:
>     pthreadVSE.dll  (MSVC/SEH)
>     pthreadGCE.dll  (GNUC/C++ EH)
>     pthreadGC.dll   (GNUC/not dependent on
>   exceptions)   pthreadVC1.dll  (MSVC/not
>   dependent on exceptions - not binary
>             compatible with pthreadVC.dll)
>     pthreadVC2.dll  (MSVC/not dependent on
>   exceptions - not binary           compatible
>   with pthreadVC1.dll or pthreadVC.dll)
>
> The GNU library archive file names
>   have correspondingly changed to:
>
> libpthreadGCEc.a    libpthreadGCc.a

If you want to see what the differences are for each of these clean up models, search for "`__CLEANUP`" in the pthreads Win32 source (there are only a few places where the different clean up models come into play).